# Registering a model as an event listener

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I'd like to know if this is a good idea to register a Model class as an CakeEventListener inside the Model's PHP file.

For example, if I created a Model called Document that implements the listener, and at the bottom of the Document.php there I register it as a listener.

```
class Document extends AppModel implements CakeEventListener
{
   .....
}

CakeEventManager::instance()->attach(ClassRegistery::init('Document'));
```

My question is about nexted calls to `ClassRegistery::init('Document')` and if the above would cause two instances of `Document` to be created.

For example, let's say I have the following in my controller.

```
class DocumentsController extends AppController
{
     public function index()
     {
         $model = ClassRegistery::init('Document');
         .....
```

How many times is `Document` instantiated?

- The first call to `ClassRegistery::init('Document')` from the controller loads the Document.php file.
- Wouldn't there be a second call to `ClassRegistery::init('Document')` from the bottom of Document.php `befoe` the first call has finished?

Would this somehow strew up the registry in CakePHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't be a problem. `ClassRegistry::init()` only instantiates the object once. Subsequent calls to `init()` return the existing object.

I would, however, suggest registering the listener in Document's `__construct` function. This feels cleaner because we aren't mixing self-executing PHP with the class file. It also allows possible injection later on which would be useful for unit tests.

Comment: thanks, but if I put it in the construct then I'm call the ::init() from inside an executing ::init() call. Do you understand? That's why I was wondering if this was a problem.

Comment: Not if you pass `$this` instead of using the class registry to init it again.